# Byte Compiler-optimisation in R

Tags: r, performance, optimization, compilation, compiler-optimization

Consider the following code in R

```
####### CODE 1 #######

test = FALSE # or TRUE
for (i in 1:10^5){
   if (test){
      DoThat(i)
   } else {
      DoThis(i)
   }
}
```

If R compiler is good I would expect that the condition of the `if` statement won't be evaluated at every single iteration. `Code 1` would then be equivalent to

```
####### CODE 2 #######

test = FALSE # or TRUE
if (test){
  for (i in 1:10^5){
      DoThat(i)
  }
} else {
  for (i in 1:10^5){
      DoThis(i)
  }
}
```

`Code 1` is easier to read but if not well compiled would be slower than `code 2`

Are the two codes equivalent (in terms of computation time) after compilation? Should I make sure to encompass my code into a function (eventually a function called `main`) to make sure compilation is well optimized?

FYI: My R version is `R 3.1.2 GUI 1.65 Mavericks build (6833)`

Comment: R is not a compiled language; it is interpreted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like something you could easily benchmark yourself (and i'll throw another option into the mix

```
DoThis<-function(x) x+2
DoThat<-function(x) x+1

f1<-function() {
    test = FALSE # or TRUE
    for (i in 1:10^5){
        if (test){
            DoThat(i)
        } else {
            DoThis(i)
        }
    }
}

f2<-function() {
    test = FALSE # or TRUE
    if (test){
        for (i in 1:10^5){
            DoThat(i)
        }
    } else {
        for (i in 1:10^5){
            DoThis(i)
        }
    }   
}

f3<-function() {
    test = FALSE # or TRUE
    if (test){
        fn<-DoThat
    } else {
        fn<-DoThis
    }
    for (i in 1:10^5){
        fn(i)
    }
}
```

and then compare with

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f1(),f2(),f3())

# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#  f1() 55.44489 57.79875 61.50379 60.65098 62.25607 118.8442   100   b
#  f2() 42.70537 44.30422 52.45846 46.37495 48.51268 499.1535   100  ab
#  f3() 41.59938 42.92486 47.29460 46.02898 47.50596 117.2711   100  a
```

as you can see they all have roughly equivalent run times on the micro-second scale.

If you were to "compile" them via `compiler::cmpfun`, the results don't change much

```
f1c = compiler::cmpfun(f1)
f2c = compiler::cmpfun(f2)
f3c = compiler::cmpfun(f3)
microbenchmark(f1c(),f2c(),f3c())

# Unit: milliseconds
#   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
#  f1c() 42.39095 45.59775 50.22462 47.38297 49.73408 132.88284   100   b
#  f2c() 41.79704 43.79836 46.87072 44.98536 48.21903 126.02609   100  a 
#  f3c() 40.07256 42.33789 45.14435 44.16019 46.32952  66.53634   100  a
```

tested with: R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10), Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

Comment: Useful to actually compile these, e.g., `f1c = compiler::cmpfun(f1)`

Comment: So, the differences in computation time between `f1`, `f2` and `f3` are just a matter of random fluctuation, and time to interpret the language, is that right? Essentially, R is smart and understand that the three functions do the exacts same thing, do I get it right?